# voltage dropping when connect pwm output pin of a microcontroller to resistor

Tags: avr, pwm

I have a circuit that measures the distance to the obstacle then i convert this value to voltage with PWM method . So far everything working properly but voltage dropping when connect pwm output pin of a microcontroller to resistor (250 ohm) for analog output. 
my setting for pwm is following :

[image]

for example when voltage on pin is 3.4 volt and i connect resistor , This problem is caused
.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Whats the voltage ? Are you exceeding the current capability of the pin ? capacitor near microcontroller vcc ?

Comment: voltage is 0-5 volt ,no i do not think

Comment: for example when voltage on pin is 3.4 volt and i connect resistor , This problem is caused

Comment: You say the voltage is dropping ... from 3.4V to what? 3.3V? 3.25V?

Comment: Driving 250 ohms to 5 volts requires 20 mA. Is the pin rated for that? This does not mean "Is the absolute maximum output of the pin 20 mA?".

Comment: @ Brian Drummond ,sometimes 1.5 or 2.4 or same 3.4 , change between them ! this result is for clock pulse 250 khz on pin

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast , i think maximmum current is 40 mA for any pin in avr

Comment: And, like I said, "this does not mean "Is the absolute maximum output of the pin 20 mA."" Please go to the data sheet and find out the expected output voltage/current combination, NOT the absolute maximum.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast , i was in wrong , it is 20mA at VCC = 5V, 10mA at VCC = 3V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the output pin may have a max rating of 40ma this does not mean that it will still retain the full Vcc voltage out.  At higher currents the voltage is reduced, the amount of voltage drop is shown in the AVR chip's data sheet in charts with titles such as :I/O PIN OUTPUT VOLTAGE vs. SINK/SOURCE CURRENT.  (Go back and find the data sheet of the AVR chip you are using).

To solve this you would need an external driver (transistor, mosfet, etc) that can provide the extra current to maintain the voltage needed.

Comment: ok , thanks ,i think that can use this circuit : http://www.electronics-lab.com/blog/?p=26458